# Detect when a react-rendered image loads

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, react-dom-server

I have a React component for rendering customized images. In a simplified form, it looks like this:

```
function MyImage(props) {
  return <img src={props.src} onLoad={props.onLoad} />
}
```

The webpage is server-rendered by `ReactDOMServer` and the `<img>` elements are (intentionally) already present in the initial HTML document. However, their `onLoad` event handlers are *not*. I believe that is a *feature* of `ReactDOMServer`.

What can sometimes happen is that some of the customized images, especially the smaller ones, can finish loading *before* JavaScript is loaded or before it starts running or at least before React sets up the `onLoad` event handlers. As a result, the `onLoad` events on these images do not cause any event handlers to be called.

Is there a way to ensure that the `onLoad` event handlers, which are set up within a React-rendered `<img>` elements, will *always* be called after the underlying images finish loading?

My most important constraints are that I would like to use React and the server-rendered HTML page needs to contain the `<img>` elements *with* their `src` attributes correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your `onLoad` handlers to the `componentDidMount()` method. See [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Comment: I do not see what you mean exactly and how it may help with my particular problem. Please clarify.

Comment: I still need the `onLoad` event handler to be called when image finishes loading, so I cannot "move" the event handlers away from the `<img>` elements. Do you mean to just call the event handler manually in `componentDidMount` (if `image.complete` is true)?

Comment: The DOM is accessible from the `componentDidMount` phase, which means your image should have finished loading. So, yes, I mean manually call the event handler inside it.

Comment: The image does not necessarily have to finish loading by the time `componentDidMount` is called. It would just be present in the DOM. But anyway, checking for it being fully loaded at that point and eventually calling the `onLoad` handler if needed should help. Please update your answer so that it is clear what you mean.